# Pause Local Video On Modal Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have seen a few solutions to a similar issue here on SO but none do what I need. I have a web page that will be displayed on a kiosk that will not have internet connection so everything is local. All of my videos are in bootstrap modals and they continue to play on modal close.

One solution removes the link entirely and so the video can't be replayed if clicked again. The other solutions in their various forms stop the video for 1/2 a second then the video continues.

**Video Modal**

```
    <!-- Modal Overview -->
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="gal_overview" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
              <div class="rl"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
                  <h2 class="text-uppercase">Overview</h2>
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="video/overview.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                        Close Video</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Last Script Tried**

```
<script>
  $('.portfolio-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {    
    var $if = $(e.delegateTarget).find('iframe');
    var src = $if.attr("src");
    $if.attr("src", '/empty.html');
    $if.attr("src", src);
  });
  </script>
```

This current code will start playing all videos in the background on page load. I'm sure I'm missing something super simple here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working answer:**

Since the iframe just points to a video file, you can change the iframe to a `<video>` and control the video much more easily.

```
<video src="video/overview.mp4"></video>
```

The `.pause()` method on the video element can then be used to actually pause the video.

```
<script>
  $('.portfolio-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var $v = $(e.delegateTarget).find('video');
    $v[0].pause();  // use [0] because jQuery returns a list
  });
</script>
```

**Initial answer:**

It sounds like you should lazily-apply the iframe's `src` attribute. So when the page loads, the iframes' `src` attributes should be `data-src`. That way no video is playing.

Then on `$('.portfolio-modal').on('show.bs.modal')`, set the `src` attribute with the contents of `data-src`. The video will play.

Then when the modal is hidden, replace `src` with `/empty.html` again.

Next time the modal is launched, the `src` will be set again, and the cycle repeats.

If you truly want to *pause* the video rather than reset the iframe, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31026234/684776) should be helpful.

Comment: `<script>
  $('.modal-body').on('click.dismiss.bs.modal', function(e) {    
    var $if = $(e.delegateTarget).find('iframe');
    var reload = $if.attr("src");
    $if.attr("src", '/empty.html');
    $if.attr("src", reload);
  });
  </script>` This is what I'm using now. Nothing is playing. As soon as you click the close button the video stops then starts playing again in the background.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example iframe `src` so I can test? I wonder if the destination is storing the "playing" state and restoring it when the iframe is reloaded.

Comment: Are you asking me for one of the videos to use?

Comment: Kind of. I think what I actually need is the page at `src`. That's not _exactly_ a video - it's a page that contains a video. It's where we'll find the logic that decides when the video pauses and plays.

Comment: A couple things: 1) Are the videos served from the same domain as the containing app? 2) If the iframes just point to `.mp4` videos, why not just use `<video>` elements so you can control them via their JavaScript API?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199848/discussion-between-cmrussell-and-michael-crenshaw).

Comment: @cmrussell updated with the solution we worked out in chat.